# Apache Tomcat HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, http, tomcat

When i run the program at first stage `index.jsp` page appear with two field of login and password and providing correct username password when i press submit button my Tomcat show such type of error

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

but i also try `GET` method but same error.

Please some one help me thanx a lot.

Comment: DID YOU USE STRUTS HIBERNATE LIKE THAT

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-login-form-with-jsp/25685 REFER THIS LINK IT MAY HELP TO YOU..

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: i want db connection type help your reference is very simple thanx for sharing

Comment: yest i try to post now thanx Prabhat

Answer (score 0):

You question doesn't contain much information about the login form and the URL handler it gets submitted to. But I guess, after clicking the submit button, the login form is submitted to a [Java servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) that doesn't implement `doGet()` or `service()` methods. Probably, it requires a POST request. So you can try to change the method attribute of the login form  to `method="POST"` and see if it helps.

Comment: please can you tell me how to post my code because when i post my code it ask for space i cant understand how to post please tell me.

Comment: You can either post a link to the web site with the index.jsp you work on or you can edit your question and add a code block (text indented by 4 spaces), there is a button for it in the editor's toolbar. And it would be helpful to write something about the servlet the login form submits to (how it's implemented).